# LNK2005 error while building cuda code for cuPrintf

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, linker-errors

I am new to visual studio and I am trying to use cuPrintf in my cuda code using visual studio 2010

```
#include "cuPrintf.cu"
#include "cuPrintf.cuh"
```

but I am getting the following error

```
gpuLBMSolver.cu.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl cuPrintf(char const *)" (?cuPrintf@@YAHPBD@Z) already defined in cuPrintf.cu.obj
1>gpuLBMSolver.cu.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl cuPrintfRestrict(int,int)" (?cuPrintfRestrict@@YAXHH@Z) already defined in cuPrintf.cu.obj
1>gpuLBMSolver.cu.obj : error LNK2005: _cudaPrintfInit already defined in cuPrintf.cu.obj
1>gpuLBMSolver.cu.obj : error LNK2005: _cudaPrintfEnd already defined in cuPrintf.cu.obj
1>gpuLBMSolver.cu.obj : error LNK2005: _cudaPrintfDisplay already defined in cuPrintf.cu.obj
```

The same code was working fine on my Linux machine... 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to include both the `.cu` and the `.cuh` file. You can include either one.

If you include the `.cu` file, following the example given in the comments in the `.cuh` file, that's all you need to do.
If you include *only* the `.cuh` file, then you will also need to build the `.cu` file in your project, and link it in.

It might also work if you simply reverse the order of including the files:

```
#include "cuPrintf.cuh"
#include "cuPrintf.cu"
```

assuming you don't try to *also* build `cuPrintf.cu` in your project.

It appears that you are including "cuPrintf.cu" in your code *and* you are separately building cuPrintf.cu in your project.  You cannot do that.

Since you are including "cuPrintf.cu", you need to delete the cuPrintf.cu file from your project source files.  (Don't delete the file, just delete the fact that it shows up in your project source files to be built.)

Comment: updated my answer.  You are doing `#include "cuPrintf.cu"` in one of your files, *and* you are separately building `cuPrintf.cu` in your project.  Do not build `cuPrintf.cu` in your project.  Just include it.